# New NVME or Old Sata SSD for boot

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sata, nvme

I'm working on a new PC build (Windows 10 Pro, possibly dual boot Linux), which I will be using the PC all day every day for work (Web Dev elopement and Graphic Design) as well as playing games. I purchased a Samsung 970 Pro 512 NVMe Drive, ostensibly to use as the system boot drive.

However, I'm starting to wonder if the performance benefits for windows specifically would be noticeable enough to warrant using it as the boot drive over an older drive I have, the Pro Evo 850. The idea of having more room on the 970 pro for Large Applications (Adobe CC) and Games while windows is contained entirely on it's own drive is appealing. It would certainly make reinstalls a lot easier, since I wouldn't have to download and install adobe again and other large programs again.

I know that technically the 970 would be better for windows, but I'm wondering how that would translate to real world benefits (outside of saving 1 second or so at boot), especially when all the other major programs and games would be loading off the newer, better drive.

Finally, if the speed different has more do do with the older drive being and 850 Evo rather than it being Sata, I might consider getting a cheap modern 128gb sata drive to dedicate to windows, and use the 850 Evo as a scratch disk.

The questions:

1. Would putting Windows on newer higher end NVMe SSD have noticeable real-world performance increase in over-all usage over having it on an older Sata SSD, assuming the rest of the programs will be on the newer higher performance NVMe SSD in either case?
2. Is giving Windows 10 it's own dedicated SSD a worthwhile practice?
3. Given a choice between a faster and smaller (120gb) SSD and an larger (250gb) and slower SSD, which is better for the OS and which is better as a scratch disk for Adobe CC?

Comment: Is there a question?  Unfortunately, hardware suggestions are off-topic at SuperUser... the state of the art and market changes frequently.  If you're looking for performance differences, please see https://www.storagereview.com/ .  If you're willing to wait a few months, there will be a variety of PCIe 4.0 devices on the market, and they will be even better than the PCI 3.0 NVMe devices available today.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's not a hardware recommendation question, it's just that the questions got lost in the background information. I've edited the original post with the questions clarified at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> Would putting Windows on newer higher end NVMe SSD have noticeable real-world performance increase in over-all usage over having it on an older SATA SSD, assuming the rest of the programs will be on the newer higher performance NVMe SSD in either case?

NVMe brings significant performance improvements.  How large of a delta really entirely depends on the memory used in each of the devices.

> Is giving Windows 10 it's own dedicated SSD a worthwhile practice?

Installing Windows 10 on an SSD will bring significant improvements.  It does not matter if you install everything to a 2 TB SSD or use two 1 TB drives one for Windows the other for storage.  The only possible benefit is the ability to upgrade one or another in the future.  However, that has nothing specifically to do with the possible performance gains, from installing Windows on an SSD.

> Given a choice between a faster and smaller (120gb) SSD and a larger (250gb) and slower SSD, which is better for the OS and which is better as a scratch disk?

"Scratch disks" do not really exist in the Windows environment.  It takes considerable effort to move files and folders that are typically kept on the same partition as Windows.  Moving these files and folders while possible might not actually be supported.  You might run into issues, for example moving your user's profile to another drive, typically prevents Windows 10 feature updates from being installed.

> However, I'm starting to wonder if the performance benefits for windows specifically would be noticeable enough to warrant using it as the boot drive over an older drive I have, the Pro Evo 850.

You would have to perform performance benchmarks to determine if the difference is actually noticable.

Comment: I've clarified that I meant a scratch disk for Adobe CC, because yeah windows doesn't have one for the OS. As for benchmarks, I understand the new faster stuff will always bench mark better. Which is why I was asking for read worlds usage. I guess another way to look at it is how much delta is needed before something would appear to perform better to an average user when it comes to using the OS?

Comment: I am not going to provide links benchmarks you can handle that yourself

Comment: I did not as for a link to benchmarks. Besides, they're pointless if you don't run them on your own rig. I was wondering if there was an information on how much of a difference between to two given bench marks is generally perceptible to the average user who isn't specifically looking for differences. Perhaps I misunderstood the term delta is used in this context..

Comment: I can’t tell you how large of a difference it will make.  There are performance differences between two brands of NVMe drives.  Starting to get the impression that you might be looking for something my answer cannot and will never provide

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and reply. I'm starting to think the answers I seek lie more in the realm of double blind tests than benchmarks.